# Merging results of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, merge, case

I know what I want to do but I'm struggling to find the best way to do it.

I have a query that is returning me some data:

```
SELECT
[Description] As [Name], month([OccuredOn]) as [Month], year([OccuredOn]) AS [Year],        COUNT([id]) AS Cnt 
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY [Description], Year([OccuredOn]), Month([OccuredOn]) 
ORDER BY  [Description],Year([OccuredOn]), month([OccuredOn])
```

The problem is I need to merge some of the results into one.

The following is what I want to do but I need to be able to merge the records of string1 and string2 into a single record of string3.

```
SELECT
CASE [Description] 
    WHEN 'String1' THEN 'String3' 
    WHEN 'String2' THEN 'String3' 
    ELSE  [Description] 
END As [Name], 
month([OccuredOn]) as [Month], year([OccuredOn]) AS [Year],  COUNT([id]) AS Cnt 
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY [Description], Year([OccuredOn]), Month([OccuredOn]) 
ORDER BY  [Description],Year([OccuredOn]), month([OccuredOn])
```

I know the above isn't the way to do it but was hoping someone could point out a way I can return my results where any descriptions with string1 or string2 return as a single unique row for that date with an accumulated count.

The above SQL obviously returns two lots of data for string1 and string2

Thanks

Comment: have you tried group by `[Name]` instead of group by `[Description]`?

Comment: I think you should check out SELECT DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to propagate your `case` to the `group by` and `order by` clauses

```
SELECT
CASE [Description] 
    WHEN 'String1' THEN 'String3' 
    WHEN 'String2' THEN 'String3' 
    ELSE  [Description] 
END As [Name], 
month([OccuredOn]) as [Month], year([OccuredOn]) AS [Year],  COUNT([id]) AS Cnt 
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY CASE [Description] 
    WHEN 'String1' THEN 'String3' 
    WHEN 'String2' THEN 'String3' 
    ELSE  [Description] 
END, Year([OccuredOn]), Month([OccuredOn]) 
ORDER BY  CASE [Description] 
    WHEN 'String1' THEN 'String3' 
    WHEN 'String2' THEN 'String3' 
    ELSE  [Description] 
END,Year([OccuredOn]), month([OccuredOn])
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was after. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i really hope his table isnt that big. case statements in groups and orders are very nonperformant

Comment: @PlantTheIdea: Well, is there a better way?

Comment: @geomagas its been a while since i worked on SQL Server, but in ANSI, Teradata, DB2, and Oracle you can group by the name of the field you derive via CASE. this allows the optimizer to use an already-processed field rather than re-derive it twice more. this is why i asked in the comments "have you tried grouping by `[Name]`?"

Comment: @PlantTheIdea: That's not the case with MS SQL. It doesn't accept field aliases in `group by` or `order by`. Unfortunate, I know... but that's how it is.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do this?

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT
      CASE [Description] 
      WHEN 'String1' THEN 'String3' 
      ELSE  [Description] 
      END As [Name], 
      month([OccuredOn]) as [Month], year([OccuredOn]) AS [Year],  COUNT([id]) AS Cnt 
      FROM MyTable 
      UNION
      SELECT
      CASE [Description] 
      WHEN 'String2' THEN 'String3' 
      ELSE  [Description] 
      END As [Name], 
      month([OccuredOn]) as [Month], year([OccuredOn]) AS [Year],  COUNT([id]) AS Cnt 
      FROM MyTable) 
GROUP BY [Description], Year([OccuredOn]), Month([OccuredOn]) 
ORDER BY  [Description],Year([OccuredOn]), month([OccuredOn])
```

Comment: if you go this direction, recommend using `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`. your grouping handles the uniqueness, no need to validate it via `UNION`.